# Cannot debug .net core app built with docker containers and docker-compose using Rider. Containers exits with code 139

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, debugging, docker-compose, rider

I am not able to attach debugger to my docker containers app using Rider. It works fine with Visual Studio (run & debug) and with only 'run' using Rider, however when I'm trying to 'run debug' on Rider, the app tries to start but after that all the containers exits with code 139 and following error:

```
LTTng-UST: Error (-17) while registering tracepoint probe. Duplicate registration of tracepoint probes having the same name is not allowed.
```

[image: docker exited containers]

I can't find any solution for that issue, neither docker logs aren't helpful. You can find configuration below.

Sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.5-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY My.App1/My.App1.csproj My.App1/
RUN dotnet restore My.App1/My.App1.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/My.App1
RUN dotnet build My.App1.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish My.App1.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.App1.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  My.App3:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp3
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.App3/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - My.App2
      - My.App5
      - My.App1
      - My.App6
      - My.app7

  My.App2:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.App2/Dockerfile

  My.App5:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp5
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.App5/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - My.App1
      - My.App6
      - My.app7
    
  My.App1:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.App1/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - My.App2


  My.App6:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.App6/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - My.App1

  My.app7:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp7
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.app7/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - My.App1
      - My.App2

  My.App4:
    image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp4
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.App4/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - My.App1
      - My.App2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your runtime version to dotnet:2.1.22-aspnetcore-runtime